# 'phing' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

Tags: php, laravel

i am a laravel developer and i have integrated aimeos in laravel.There is a command specific to aimeos
phing -f phing.xml i18n which i try to run this command in the command line inside my laravel project
directory it gives me error

'phing' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

please note that i have installed phing package through composer and it successfully installed because
i can see it in my composer.json file

```html
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "laravel"
    ],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.3|^8.0",
        "aimeos/ai-client-html": "2020.10.x-dev",
        "aimeos/aimeos-laravel": "~2020.10",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.4",
        "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0",
        "gettext/gettext": "^5.5",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.0.1",
        "laravel/framework": "^8.12",
        "laravel/jetstream": "^2.1",
        "laravel/sanctum": "^2.6",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.5",
        "livewire/livewire": "^2.0",
        "phing/phing": "^2.16"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "facade/ignition": "^2.5",
        "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "laravel/sail": "^1.0.1",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.4.2",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^5.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.3.3"
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
            "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
        },
        "classmap": [
            "ext/moudhah/lib/custom/src",
            "ext/moudhah/controller/common/src",
            "ext/moudhah/controller/frontend/src",
            "ext/moudhah/controller/jobs/src",
            "ext/moudhah/client/html/src",
            "ext/moudhah/client/jsonapi/src",
            "ext/moudhah/admin/jqadm/src",
            "ext/moudhah/admin/jsonadm/src"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "scripts": {
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@php artisan migrate",
            "@php artisan vendor:publish --tag=public --force",
            "\\Aimeos\\Shop\\Composer::join"
        ],
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    }
}
```

the reason why i posted that question here instead of aimeos forum because i think it is some kind of
composer issue

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't add it to your path it won't be found. Most (all?) packages installed via composer have their exec's in the `vendor/bin` folder. `phing` is no exception to this.

Assuming you're on Linux you need to run

```
./vendor/bin/phing
```

from inside your project folder.

Comment: i am actually i am on windows and i added the path D:\moudhah\vendor\bin\phing first in my user variable (Path) and after that restarted window but it didn't worked after that i added that path in my system variable(Path) and then restarted the window but again it didn't worked .Please note that path(D:\moudhah\vendor\bin\phing) is correct because i checked that in my directory

Comment: The path is `D:\moudhah\vendor\bin` -  `phing` is the executable (might be `phing.exe` on Windows)

Comment: I am late to the party. But on Windows PHP files are not directly run with their interpreter. And `phing` is a PHP file. So you need to call `php D:\moudhah\vendor\bin\phing`